# Sorting CSV file with delimiter in Python

Tags: python, csv

How to do read a .csv file with the following content

```
$C=2$A=3$B=1$
```

Then create a new .csv file with the same content but the `$` changed into `,` and sorted alphabetically like the following:

```
A=3,B=1,C=2
```

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's my following code. It ended up giving an extra comma at the beginning of the output.

```
input = csv.reader(open('inputfile.csv','r'), delimiter='$')
output = open('outputfile.csv','w')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for column in input:
        writer.writerow(sorted(column))
        print (sorted(column))
finally:
    out.close()
```

Right now my input is:

> $C=2$A=3$B=1$

and my output is:

> ,A=3,B=1,C=2

I want it to be:

> A=3,B=1,C=2

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything yet, I suggest you take a look at the `csv` module.

Comment: I ended up with ,A=3,B=1,C=2 How do you remove the first coma?

Comment: The `csv.writer` object has a `delimiter` keyword argument.

Comment: Yup, I tried that and it changed every $ into , the problem is that I ended up with more comma than I want at the beginning of the string.

Comment: OK please post what you've tried in your question. And maybe some example input and example output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('test.csv') as in_file, open('new.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in csv.reader(in_file, delimiter='$'):
        out_file.write(','.join(sorted(line)[2:])+'\n')
```

Basically what this does is:

- open the input as `in_file`
- open the output as `out_file`
- initializes a CSV reader with `$` as the delimiter using `in_file` as the input file
- iterates through each row doing the following:

  - sort all of the elements (after parsing)
  - discard the first 2 (since they'll always be empty strings due to the start/end delimiters on each line)
  - recombine those elements using `,` as the delimiter
  - write that out to the file with a trailing newline `\n`

**edit**:  fixed for the start/end `$` symbols by removing the empty elements that get parsed out of the CSV (the `[2:]` bit)

Comment: Can you do 2 'open' using one 'with'?

Comment: Yup, tested the code myself with your input and a little extra I mocked up

Comment: It still give out extra comma at the beginning. Strange.

Comment: @user1546610 did you use the updated/edited version?  I had failed to notice the start/end `$` when I first did it so my input didn't quite match yours, but it should now

Comment: Thanks! I must use [1:] instead of [2:] also. I still use 2.6, maybe that's why. Thank you.

Comment: @JAB yup, perhaps that's clearer even since removing from the front and back before sorting is a bit more intuitive than discarding two elements afterwards

Comment: @user1546610 `','.join(sorted(line[1:-1]))` should also work (because `'$C=2$A=3$B=1$'.split('$')` -> `['', 'C=2', 'A=3', 'B=1', '']`). Also, Daniel, a more Pythonic way to do it might be `csv.writer(out_file).writerows(sorted(line[1:-1]) for line in csv.reader(in_file, delimiter='$'))` (though not necessarily all in one line, of course). (Also, it's usually a good idea to open files used with `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` with `newline=''`, just in case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `csv.reader` to read the file with the delimiter set to `'$'`. Then for each row returned, strip out the empty elements and sort the rest:

```
row = sorted([item for item in row if item])
```